# Is this a good approach to continue developing a ruby on rails web application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this a good approach to continue developing a ruby on rails web application?

here is a signup sample:

**user model:** user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :username
validates_presence_of :email, :name, :password, :username
end
```

**signup controller:** signup-controller.rb

```
class SignupController < ApplicationController
def init
    @user = User.new
    render :template => '/signup/signup'
end

def signup
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.valid?
        @user.save
        render :template => '/signup/success'
    else
               #bla bla bla
    end
end
end
```

**signup page:** signup.html.erb

```
  <h1>Signup!!!</h1>
  <%= form_for(@user, :url => signup_path) do |f| %>
   Name: <%= f.text_field  :name %> </br>
   Email <%= f.text_field :email %> </br>
   Username: <%= f.text_field :username %> </br>
   Password: <%= f.text_field :password %> </br>
   <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
  <% end %>
```

**after signup process complete:** success.html.erb

```
<h1>signup successfull :) </h1>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/index/signup' => 'signup#init', :as => :signup_index
post '/index/signup/' => 'signup#signup', :as => :signup
```

Comment: Do you have a more pointed question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Michael Durrant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12380438/467546) has given some great advice that I'll be careful not to copy. However, there are some things that I would like to add that are more code specific.

### Preparing for Rails 4.0

I'm assuming this is either a practice application or something that is early on in development. Regardless of which is true for you, I think you'll be better off if you go ahead an adopt some of the new changes in Rails 4.0.

One of the new changes is [Strong Parameters](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/). Rails will be dropping the use of `attr_accessible` in the model and creating a new way of dealing with mass-assignment in the controller. This will allow you to "dynamically" change which fields can be updated depending on different users or [namespaces](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

Updating the code you have written so far isn't very difficult. I've gone ahead and made the key changes myself.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'strong_parameters'
```

**user model:** `user.php`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection
  validates_presence_of :email, :name, :password, :username
end
```

**users controller:** `users_controller.php`

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to login_path, :notice => "You have signed up successfully. You may now login!"
    else
      render :new, :alert => "There was an problem creating your account"
    end
  end

private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :name, :password, :username)
  end
end
```

**Note:** I made some changes to `users_controller.php` other than using strong parameters.

1. I changed the action names to match the [Rails resource verbs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).
2. Instead of calling `.valid?` and `.save`, I changed the `if` statement to only use `.save`. This is because `.save` will call `.valid?` and return false accordingly.
3. I modified/added `redirect_to` and `render` calls to the `create` action. The `redirect_to` call is a more important change because it helps prevent double form submission.

### Using a Partial for your Forms

One of the cool features of working with views in Rails are [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#partial-layouts). A partial allows you to extract a snippet of HTML that is used in more than one place. By using a partial you can write the code for your `form_for` in one file and use it in the `new` and `edit` actions. Keeping your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Also, I noticed that you didn't use the `<label>` tag in your form. This is something that I think is very important because it improves user experience.

**Note:** I've changed the signup page filename to match the changes in my version of `users_controller.php`.

**signup page:** `new.html.erb`

```
<h1>Signup!!</h1>
<%= render :partial => "form" %>
```

**user form:** `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />

  <%= f.label :email, "Email Address" %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %><br />

  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %><br />

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br />

  <%= f.submit "Sign Up" %>
<% end %>
```

If you have any questions to something I've posted please ask. I'll try to explain anything I can.

Comment: Thank you very much. but should the controller name be the same as the model name? i mean user.rb with controller users_controller.rb instead of signin_controller.rb ??

Comment: @user1664409 Yes, because the controller is providing actions that work with the `User` model. The `new` and `create` actions are going to add a new user to the database. Have a look at Ryan Bate's screencast on building authentication from scratch. You'll see that he uses the `UsersController` for the signup but he creates a `SessionController` to handle the actual login. He does this because the controller and action names explain each other. http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Answer (score 1):

Getting rails right is all about following its conventions.

- Change init to new
- Change signup to create.
- use resources :users for routes.

Even better follow a railscast on using authLogic or Devise rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Thanks, but should the controller name be the same as the model name? i mean user.rb with controller users_controller.rb.